# How to iterate over a list in an Elm view?

Tags: svg, elm

I am trying to add rectangles to an SVG using a view in Elm the following way:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  let
      log1 = Debug.log "Time: " model.time
      log2 = Debug.log "Coords: " model.coordinates
      rects = [ ("200", "200"), ("210","201"), ("220", "202") ]
  in
    svg
    [ width "700", height "700", viewBox "0 0 500 500" ]
        [ rect [ x "100", y "100", width "600", height "600", fill "gray" ] []
        , List.map (\ coord -> (rect [ x (fst coord), y (snd coord), width "1", height "1", fill "black" ] [])) rects
        ]
```

Is there a way to get an VirtualDom.Node type out of the map instead of List?

Error message:

```
    The 1st element has this type:

        VirtualDom.Node a

    But the 2nd is:

        List (Svg a)

Hint: All elements should be the same type of value so that we can iterate
through the list without running into unexpected values.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just concatenate the lists together like this:

```
svg
[ width "700", height "700", viewBox "0 0 500 500" ]
    ([ rect [ x "100", y "100", width "600", height "600", fill "gray" ] [] ]
      ++ List.map (\ coord -> (rect [ x (fst coord), y (snd coord), width "1", height "1", fill "black" ] [])) rects)
```

Since the first list is a single element, you could also use the cons operator as well

```
svg
[ width "700", height "700", viewBox "0 0 500 500" ]
    (rect [ x "100", y "100", width "600", height "600", fill "gray" ] []
      :: List.map (\ coord -> (rect [ x (fst coord), y (snd coord), width "1", height "1", fill "black" ] [])) rects)
```